# I want to change animation of sticky text according to scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, gsap

I have been trying the sticky scroll animation where the text remains fixed at its position and changes according to scroll. Images are placed according to scroll and text is changing according to it. but the problem is when it changes its not giving a good animation and I have tried several methods but I am not able to change the animation between the text change.

```
<div class="desktopPhotos">
  <div class="desktopPhoto">
    <h1>Red</h1>
    <p>Red is a color ergy.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="desktopPhoto">
    <h1>Green</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="desktopPhoto">
    <h1>Blue</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="desktopPhoto">
    <h1>Blue</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is sticky text.
Currently its changing according to scroll with animation in JavaScript which I want to change.

```
const details = gsap.utils.toArray(".desktopContentSection:not(:first-child)")
const photos = gsap.utils.toArray(".desktopPhoto:not(:first-child)")


gsap.set(photos, {
    yPercent: 101,
    opacity: 100
})

const allPhotos = gsap.utils.toArray(".desktopPhoto")

let mm = gsap.matchMedia();

mm.add("(min-width: 600px)", () => {

    console.log("desktop")

    ScrollTrigger.create({
        trigger: ".gallery",
        start: "top top",
        end: "bottom bottom",
        pin: ".right"
    })

    details.forEach((detail, index) => {

        let headline = detail.querySelector("h1")
        let animation = gsap.timeline()
            .to(photos[index], {
                yPercent: 0
            })
            .set(allPhotos[index], {
                autoAlpha: 0
            })
        ScrollTrigger.create({
            trigger: headline,
            start: "top 40%",
            end: "top 30%",
            animation: animation,
            scrub: true,
            markers: false
        })
    })

    return () => {
        console.log("mobile")
    };
});
```

I have tried this but not sure about it as I am a JS beginner. I need this project for my school's it-fest , please help me out.

Here is website from which I was inspired to use this element. (the fixed text and image moving section) [link for website](https://riveal.fr). I was hoping of a animation like this website's sticky text.

Thank you in advance! Hoping for a positive response.